# Когда стоит остановиться добавлять все в переменные?

Tags: javascript, переменные

Я только начинаю изучать js, но уже знаю, что любая переменная сидит в памяти. Однако создавая свои первые скрипты сразу задаюсь вопросом, стоит ли пренебрегать удобством чтения кода перед свободной памятью? Или может те крохи памяти, что занимают переменные не стоят удобства? Где грань?

Comment: _уже знаю, что любая переменная сидит в памяти_ - не любая

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На начальном этапе изучения JS, Вам не нужно вникать в такие тонкости потому что быстро "перегорите" и пропадет желание учить дальше. Но читаемость кода - всегда важнее его длины. Вы сейчас помните, что сократили в своем коде, но попробуйте глянуть на него через парочку месяцев - тогда удивитесь, что можно было забыть и начнете писать понятно без сокращений и с комментариями.

P.S. Если все-таки интересны тонкости вот [хорошая статья про управление памятью в JS](https://habr.com/company/ruvds/blog/338150/)

P.P.S. А вот немного юмора по написанию кода на JS:) [Как писать неподдерживаемый код](https://learn.javascript.ru/write-unmain-code)

Comment: как оказалось, периодически полезно почитать о неподдерживаемом коде. Вот прочитал, и в некоторых местах узнал себя)